# How to mount WebDav filesystem on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mavericks, webdav

Trying to do the following:

```
mkdir /Volumes/temp
mount_webdav davs://myusername@webdav.yandex.ru:443 /Volumes/temp
```

It doesn't return any error, but `/Volumes/temp` is empty in result.

Here are the details of connection required ([mac](http://help.yandex.ru/disk/webdav/webdav-mac.xml) / [linux](http://help.yandex.ru/disk/webdav/webdav-linux.xml#dolphin)), they are in Russian, but you may see details on screenshots.

Upd. The following works:

```
mount_webdav -i https://webdav.yandex.ru:443 /Volumes/temp
```

But in this case I have to input user name and password. I've tried the following:

```
mount_webdav https://myusername:mypass@webdav.yandex.ru:443 /Volumes/temp
mount_webdav -s https://myusername:mypass@webdav.yandex.ru:443 /Volumes/temp
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In (at least) 10.9 and 10.10, mounting via WebDAV via the command line isn't easy -- the mount_webdav command does not work the way it is documented and fails silently leaving an empty mount point while the interactive version (-i) of the command works as expected. The non-interactive version files (specifically storing and retrieving of the login/password).

Here is a solution: https://github.com/childrss/webdav

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to mount a WebDAV-enabled server directory in OS X is like the example you mentioned works. The reason it's asking for a username and password is because you've specified the `-i` argument, which denotes `Interactive mode` (you are prompted for the username and password).

To mount a webdav for a certain user you would use like this:

```
mount_webdav https://webdav.yandex.ru/username/ /Volumes/temp/
```

If you don't want to be prompted for the username and password then you can store the user credentials in your keychain.

see [Apple's MOUNT_WEBDAV man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/mount_webdav.8.html) for more information.

Comment: I looked for the documentation you are referring to when was trying (that is why I've used option `i`). But it says nothing about keychain. I've just tried to use your approach, but it didn't help. It asked for permission to use keychain when I tried to connect first time, but the connection again wasn't created.

Comment: @LA_, how do you mean `the connection wasn't created`? it didn't connect, or save the connection? and did you try it with the port added also?

Comment: Unfortunately, `mount_webdav` doesn't return any result in both cases when connection is established and when it is not. So, each time I check the result by verifying content of `/Volumes/temp`. So, after command execution, `/Volumes/temp` was empty. I've tried with port number and without, `https` and `http`.

Comment: @LA_, are the login credentials being stored in the keychain and being used for the connection? from what you're describing it almost appears as if it's not.

Comment: I do not know how to check if they are really used, but when I try to connect, OSX asks my permission to use the keychain data.

Comment: Btw, when I input url with the port number in the keychain, port number is automatically deleted after record saving.

Comment: Here is some instruction how to pass login and name to mount_webdav - http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020207214002198&query=mount_webdav, but I can not understand it :(

Comment: In my case this command fails silently and nothing happens... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like [ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com) that has a graphical interface and helps you set up and maintain the webDAV mount. Faster, too, and has some extra features.

Comment: Sounds good. What are the extra features that you use? Can you give an example of how to use the mount feature?

Comment: There is other tools in the App Store these days too: [ocsmount](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/ocsmount/id1411490371?l=en&mt=12), [Mountain Duck](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/mountain-duck/id1024974133?l=en&mt=12), [Transmit](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/transmit-5/id1436522307?l=en&mt=12), [Forklift](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/forklift-file-manager-and-ftp-sftp-webdav-amazon-s3-client/id412448059?l=en&mt=12).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to make automatic downloads through a command-line script connecting to a WebDav filesystem and found an open source software (for Mac and Windows) which really helped!

**Cyberduck**: https://cyberduck.io/

It provides both graphical user-interface and command-line options.